# Incorrect conversion when decimal point embedded in VT_BSTR and German locale used

Tags: c++, excel, locale, decimal-point

I have a piece of code(c++) that is writing some floating point values to excel like this:

```
...
values[ position ].bstrVal = formattedValue;
values[ position ].vt = VT_BSTR;
...
```

as you can see those floating point values are stored in the form of string and the decimal point is formatted in different ways, for example:
"110.000000", "20.11" etc. (this example is for English locale)

Now it works perfectly when English locale is used. However when I switch to German locale in the Control Panel the decimal point is changed to "," (and that's fine) but after passing those localized strings to Excel they are not correctly converted. For example in case of writing "110,000000" I'm getting 100 millions in excel. Other values like "20,11" stay as a text.

The only way to fix this is to overwrite the decimal point with "." in my program before writing to Excel. Any ideas why the conversion is not locale-aware when using VT_BSTR?

I should also add that I tried to switch the locale in my program from default one to German - still no luck.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you should show your code which does the conversion. we don't see anything here, just that you assign a string to a string variable. It is impossible to say without seeing the related code, but if you just write the `float` to `VARIANT` (as `VT_R4`) Excel would automatically format it according to the current locale.

Comment: I'm not doing any conversion, I'm just writing those string values (that contain localized floating point values) to Excel cells. It is Excel that is doing the conversion. And about writing as VT_R4: yes that is obvious it will work. Unfortunately I have a large code base that is not easy to redesign. It has to be passed in the form of BSTR.

Comment: It makes sense. You are writing already formatted values. Excel tries to interpret them same as if you enter them manually. If you would enter this string manually, you would get excel show the same 'incorrect' values (which are actually correct). What happens if you write values as numbers? Otherwise, you need to format `formattedValue` according to current locale.

Comment: why is your `formattedValue` always formatted for German? Where do you get this value from?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing and what I described in my post. I have a German locale in Control Panel enabled and I'm writing LOCALIZED strings (with ',' as a decimal point) and I'm getting incorrect values in excel.... (formattedValue contains localized floating point values. When English locale is enabled there are strings like "10.145". When German locale enabled there is "10,145")

Comment: What methods of excel API are you using?

Comment: I'm writing to ranges, so for example Excel::RangePtr and the only call related to formatting is "ptrOutputRange->AutoFormat(Excel::xlRangeAutoFormatSimple, true, vtMissing, true, true, vtMissing, true);". Also some standard way of opening/saving.

Answer (score 1):

It is never a good idea to let Excel guess at the value type.  Do **not** use VT_BSTR, a currency value should be of variant type VT_CY.  Assign the cyVal member with the value.  It is an 8 byte integer value (int64 member of type LONGLONG), the currency amount multiplied by 10,000.  Ten thousand :)